# CSS: Hide parent if child is :empty?

Tags: css, selector

I want to hide the parent `<li>` tag if its child `<a>` tag is empty. So in the following example I would like to hide the second `<li>`:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="test1.html">Test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can reach the `<a>` via li `a:empty` and that works fine. But how do I get to its parent, the `<li>` ? Only CSS solutions, please... thanks!

Comment: How do you get this empty element? tehres no parent selector in css. I think best solution is check before if the element is empty or not

Comment: The empty element is provided by a partner company. They are leaving the whole node in the code even though it's not neccessary. And as every list element has a css declaration I wanted to identify the empty ones to hide them at all. The solution provided from @Gerard is just perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only CSS solution is the `has()` pseudo selector. Unfortunately, it's not yet supported by [Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

You may want to consider a [polyfill](https://github.com/jplhomer/polyfill-css-has) until then.

```css
li:has(a:empty) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="test1.html">Test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is awesome and absolutely works for my problem - thank you so much!